# Very Simple Quesiton About Usage of "over"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I have a simple question. I am wondering the reason why there is "over" in this sentence:

> The boss of robotics company Boston Dynamics has confessed he once
> nudged his one-year-old daughter **over** to work out how people balance.

If I sad this sentence I would say "he once nudged his one-year-old daughter to work out how people balance." without "over". So does "over" contributes any additional meaning to this sentence? If it does, what is this? If it is not, why is there "over" in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push somebody over, you make them fall to the ground. When you nudge somebody over, you push them more gently usually in order to attract their attention or, in this case, to test out the boss's theory on how people balance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andrew. Thereby there is a verb of "nudge over" which is I suppose kind of phrasal verb. Is that right?

Comment: @grammerian I couldn't find any definition of this phrasal verb, so I assumed it's just a "gentle/caring/light" variant of "push over"...

Comment: I see. Even if it doesn't exist in the dictionary with "over", ıt is kind of "push over".